# DataTable (JQuery): how to switch language with browser language?

Tags: python, django, datatables

I use DataTable in my Django project and currently doing internationalisation of my apps

I would like DataTable change with browser language as for my templates.

I have found the way to change language with DataTable option

```
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
    lengthMenu: [5,10],
    "language": {
    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
    }
});
```

is their a simple way doing it?
or should I test for browser language and have a switch to initialize var table?

something like that (pseudocode):

````
if browser.lang == 'english'{
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
    lengthMenu: [5,10],
});
} 
else {
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
    lengthMenu: [5,10],
    "language": {
    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
    }
});
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a comparision between:

```
var lang = navigator.languages && navigator.languages[0] || 
           navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```

Var `language` is different on current browsers

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Synapsido that show me the way...
below the code I use

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {

        if(window.navigator.language == 'fr-FR'){
            var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
                lengthMenu: [5,10],
                "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
                }
            });
        } else {
            var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
                lengthMenu: [5,10],
            });
        }
```